# Warning "JSF1064: Unable to find or serve resource " after migrating from Glassfish to Wildfly

Tags: jsf, resources, wildfly

everyone.

I have an application which I was using Glassfish as my server. Then, I decided to migrate the entire application to Wildfly.

After I migrated the application I have got this log when I run it:

```
 18:14:07,769 WARNING [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (default task-30) JSF1064: Unable to find or serve resource, bootstrap.min.css, from library, bootstrap/css.
18:14:07,787 WARNING [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (default task-32) JSF1064: Unable to find or serve resource, metisMenu.css, from library, metisMenu/dist.
18:14:07,796 WARNING [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (default task-33) JSF1064: Unable to find or serve resource, font-awesome.css, from library, font-awesome-4.4.0/css.
18:14:07,875 WARNING [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (default task-40) JSF1064: Unable to find or serve resource, kendo.common.min.css, from library, css/kendo.
18:14:07,881 WARNING [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (default task-41) JSF1064: Unable to find or serve resource, kendo.rtl.min.css, from library, css/kendo.
18:14:07,918 WARNING [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (default task-42) JSF1064: Unable to find or serve resource, bootstrap-lightbox.css, from library, bootstrap/bootstrap-lightbox.
18:14:07,918 WARNING [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (default task-47) JSF1064: Unable to find or serve resource, datepicker.css, from library, datepicker/css.
18:14:07,923 WARNING [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (default task-44) JSF1064: Unable to find or serve resource, bootstrap-table.css, from library, bootstrap/bootstrap-table/src.
18:14:07,937 WARNING [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (default task-43) JSF1064: Unable to find or serve resource, kendo.default.min.css, from library, css/kendo.
18:14:07,961 WARNING [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (default task-52) JSF1064: Unable to find or serve resource, bootstrap.min.js, from library, bootstrap/js.
18:14:07,971 WARNING [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (default task-54) JSF1064: Unable to find or serve resource, bootstrap-table-filter-control.js, from library, bootstrap/bootstrap-table/src/extensions/filter-control.
18:14:07,977 WARNING [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (default task-56) JSF1064: Unable to find or serve resource, metisMenu.min.js, from library, metisMenu/dist.
18:14:07,977 WARNING [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (default task-53) JSF1064: Unable to find or serve resource, bootstrap-table-export.js, from library, bootstrap/bootstrap-table/src/extensions/export.
18:14:07,978 WARNING [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (default task-57) JSF1064: Unable to find or serve resource, bootstrap-lightbox.js, from library, bootstrap/bootstrap-lightbox.
18:14:07,991 WARNING [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (default task-60) JSF1064: Unable to find or serve resource, addhtml.js, from library, js/jsPDF/plugins.
18:14:07,990 WARNING [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (default task-59) JSF1064: Unable to find or serve resource, jspdf.js, from library, js/jsPDF.
18:14:07,982 WARNING [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (default task-55) JSF1064: Unable to find or serve resource, ga.js, from library, bootstrap/bootstrap-table.
18:14:08,010 WARNING [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (default task-62) JSF1064: Unable to find or serve resource, cell.js, from library, js/jsPDF/plugins.
18:14:08,010 WARNING [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (default task-64) JSF1064: Unable to find or serve resource, split_text_to_size.js, from library, js/jsPDF/plugins.
18:14:08,009 WARNING [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (default task-61) JSF1064: Unable to find or serve resource, from_html.js, from library, js/jsPDF/plugins.
18:14:08,016 WARNING [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (default task-5) JSF1064: Unable to find or serve resource, bootstrap-datepicker.js, from library, datepicker/js.
18:14:08,018 WARNING [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (default task-3) JSF1064: Unable to find or serve resource, jquery.mask.min.js, from library, jquery-mp/dist.
18:14:08,024 WARNING [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (default task-6) JSF1064: Unable to find or serve resource, standard_fonts_metrics.js, from library, js/jsPDF/plugins.
18:14:08,023 WARNING [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (default task-8) JSF1064: Unable to find or serve resource, bootstrap-table.js, from library, bootstrap/bootstrap-table/src.
18:14:08,017 WARNING [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (default task-63) JSF1064: Unable to find or serve resource, addimage.js, from library, js/jsPDF/plugins.
18:14:08,240 WARNING [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (default task-9) JSF1064: Unable to find or serve resource, bootstrap.min.js, from library, bootstrap/js.
18:14:08,251 WARNING [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (default task-2) JSF1064: Unable to find or serve resource, bootstrap-table.js, from library, bootstrap/bootstrap-table/src.
18:14:08,259 WARNING [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (default task-10) JSF1064: Unable to find or serve resource, bootstrap-table-export.js, from library, bootstrap/bootstrap-table/src/extensions/export.
18:14:08,271 WARNING [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (default task-11) JSF1064: Unable to find or serve resource, bootstrap-table-filter-control.js, from library, bootstrap/bootstrap-table/src/extensions/filter-control.
18:14:08,275 WARNING [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (default task-13) JSF1064: Unable to find or serve resource, ga.js, from library, bootstrap/bootstrap-table.
18:14:08,280 WARNING [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (default task-16) JSF1064: Unable to find or serve resource, metisMenu.min.js, from library, metisMenu/dist.
18:14:08,284 WARNING [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (default task-15) JSF1064: Unable to find or serve resource, bootstrap-lightbox.js, from library, bootstrap/bootstrap-lightbox.
18:14:08,853 WARNING [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (default task-14) JSF1064: Unable to find or serve resource, jspdf.js, from library, js/jsPDF.
18:14:08,857 WARNING [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (default task-12) JSF1064: Unable to find or serve resource, addhtml.js, from library, js/jsPDF/plugins.
18:14:08,861 WARNING [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (default task-17) JSF1064: Unable to find or serve resource, from_html.js, from library, js/jsPDF/plugins.
18:14:08,865 WARNING [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (default task-21) JSF1064: Unable to find or serve resource, cell.js, from library, js/jsPDF/plugins.
18:14:08,869 WARNING [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (default task-20) JSF1064: Unable to find or serve resource, addimage.js, from library, js/jsPDF/plugins.
18:14:08,874 WARNING [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (default task-19) JSF1064: Unable to find or serve resource, split_text_to_size.js, from library, js/jsPDF/plugins.
18:14:08,878 WARNING [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (default task-22) JSF1064: Unable to find or serve resource, standard_fonts_metrics.js, from library, js/jsPDF/plugins.
18:14:08,931 WARNING [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (default task-23) JSF1064: Unable to find or serve resource, bootstrap-datepicker.js, from library, datepicker/js.
18:14:08,935 WARNING [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (default task-24) JSF1064: Unable to find or serve resource, jquery.mask.min.js, from library, jquery-mp/dist.
```

I imagine that it is a problem related to the path of my resource folder that includes all the libraries mentioned in the server log. In my version running on Glassfish, my web.xml file contains this set for the context-param to indicate where my resource folder is:

```
<context-param>
   <param-name>
     javax.faces.WEBAPP_RESOURCES_DIRECTORY
   </param-name>
   <param-value>/resources</param-value>
</context-param>
```

I copied it to the web.xml file in the Wildfly's version as well. It was working fine until the migration. Everything else seems to work properly (the beans, entity classes, etc), except the link to my resource folder. I have searched the solution but haven't found it.

I appreciate any help. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5):

I had the same warnings, but only with Firefox. Daniel.lichtenberger's [post](https://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=48&t=55047&start=10) explains well the issue and how to solve it.

Summarized, Firefox's [RCWN](https://slides.com/valentingosu/race-cache-with-network-2017#/) makes two simultaneous requests and cancels the slowest, resulting in the broken pipe warning. To disable RCWN type `about:config` in Firefox and disable `network.http.rcwn.enable`